# Custom logging in SSIS

Tags: logging, ssis, ssis-2012

I use SSIS (thru dtexec, not Agent) to run some tasks.

dtexec outputs its log in stdout, then I `>>` it into a file. That works fine for me, but of course I can use another way if needed.

My issue is that dtexec's log is too verbose. I'd like to choose what exactly I want it to log. The real important info I need is to know if foreach containers had found any file to process and which ones, and also Execute Process Task's process' stdout output. If I could log Execute SQL Task's `select` outputs it would also be great.

If I could just disable some Data Flow Tasks output, it would already help a lot.

Is there any place to do these things, or some tutorial teaching how to configure log? Most stuff I found in Google were about script tasks, that's not my case.

Comment: Are you able to edit the SSIS packages themselves or are you just trying to modify what is logged via dtexec.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to log to a database - you just direct logging to a SQL Server log provider and it will populate (and generate if required) a sysssislog table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246.aspx

From there on, you can use any tool you like to query and filter the output.  My favourite is Excel via a Data Connection for easy refresh, sorting and filtering.

You do need to add a scheduled delete task, otherwise this table will just grow and grow.